# How does caching in Spring Boot work when data is updated in the database?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I have to use an old Oracle database to fetch the data through one of my GET calls with my Spring Boot controller. Now the catch is this -

1. This is a new API, and an old legacy service updates the records in the DB. This new API's task is to only fetch the data from the DB. So no other methods to update or create data is in this new API.
2. Also, there is no direct access to the DB if I want to implement or make changes anything there that will help my cause.

Given these above conditions, is there a way I can use any of the Spring supported cache providers such as Redis, to automatically update the cache or evict the cache once the data has changed on the DB?

I know I can use `@CachePut` or `@CacheEvict` to control my cache. But this is applicable only when I have methods that update or save something to the DB.  So is there any workaround so I can implement caching in this scenario?

Edit 1: Adding code
This is my controller

```
@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#userId")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUserDetails(@PathVariable String userId) {
  // some other code to parse userId to Long
  user = userRepository.findOne(usrId);
  // other code
  return user;
}
```

Comment: What code if any do you have already?. How are you initially populating your cache?

Comment: Added. With every GET call, cache is populated. That's totally fine. Now, if the data changes on the DB, there is no way to get to update my cache, or worst case evict my cache so that no stale data is being shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use REDIS Pub-Sub and listen to update or db event from another app via Redis PubSub Messaging and update or evict your cache in your local system

Refer : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-pub-sub